# zf2 how to call invokables

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have an `IndexController`, where I am trying to call a mail service class that was written in the `Utility` folder.

My Folder Strucure is like this:

```
Module 
    Application
        src
            Application
                Controller
                    IndexController
                Model
                Utility
                    SendMailClass
                View
```

In my `IndexController.php`

```
public function testAction()
{
    $obj1 = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SendEmailClass');

    $res = $obj1->sendEmail($test);
}
```

In my `Utility` folder:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Utility;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;  
use Zend\Debug\Debug;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

class SendEmailClass
{           
    public function __construct(){
        echo "Constructor Called";
    }

    public function sendEmail($mailInfo)
    {       
        $mail ='test function called';

        return $mail;
        exit;
    }
}
```

In my `Module`, module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'SendEmailClass' => function ($sm) {
                $sendEmailClass = $sm->get('Lib\Utility\SendEmailClass'); 
                $sendEmailClassObj = new SendEmailClass($sendEmailClass);
                return $sendEmailClassObj;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

In my `Module`, module_config.php,

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers'   => array(
        'invokables'    => array(
            'Users\Controller\Users'    =>  'Users\Controller\UsersController',
            'Lib\Controller\Locations'  =>  'Lib\Controller\LocationsController', 
            'Lib\Utility\SendEmailClass'    =>  'Lib\Utility\SendEmailClass', 
        ),
    ),
);
```

How should I get the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the code from your `module.php`. To get an invokable class you don't need to define a factory.  In your test action you can simply do:

```
$service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Utility\SendEmailClass');
```

But you have to register the service under a key named `service_manager` in your config array like this and you should also point to the `Application` folder. You don't have a `lib` folder in your current structure.

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables'    => array(
        'Application\Utility\SendEmailClass' => 'Application\Utility\SendEmailClass', 
    )
)
```

The controllers key is specifically for controller classes, not for other services like your email service.

If you want the service also available under the alias `SendEmailClass` then you can add this to your `service_manager` config:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    // your previous invokables service config:
    'invokables'    => array(
        'Application\Utility\SendEmailClass' => 'Application\Utility\SendEmailClass', 
    ),
    // added an alias for the SendEmailClass
    'aliases'    => array(
        'SendEmailClass' => 'Application\Utility\SendEmailClass'
    )
)
```

Now this will also works in your controller:

```
$service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('SendEmailClass');
```

Comment: Actually i am having 4 modules, suppose if i am making the SendEmailClass.php in the 4th module, how can i access the SendEmailClass commonly

Comment: @user3929758 Like I wrote you can get it from the service manager in any module

Comment: Thanks @Wilt tried to put in the application_config.php, and now its work throughtout the project. Hope i am right.

Comment: @user3929758 You can also add it the the `module.config.php` in your `Application` module (so in folder `module/Application/config/module.config.php`. That is the proper location for this config. If it works then it would be nice to "accept" my answer.